# Include trimmed multipage PDF in XeTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdfpages, crop

I have a multipage PDF manuscript (for example, `my_PDF.pdf`) that I would like to include in a new document. I would also like to trim/clip off the header and footer from each page of this included pdf.

In the past, with regular LaTeX, I have done this very simply with something like

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}  
  \includepdf[pages={1,2},trim=0.45in 0.625in 0.45in 0.625in, offset=0.25in 0in, width=6in, clip=true, pagecommand={}]{my_PDF}
\end{document}
```

as described at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics.

However, this time I need to do it in XeTeX for Unicode support, and the above method doesn't work because clipping isn't supported yet in XeTeX. I've managed to come very close by using the nice `adjustbox` package, which lets you (almost) transparently redefine the `\includegraphics` macro in a way that supports clipping:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} % Something wrong with my compiler setup
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}

\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}  
  \includepdf[pages={1,2},trim=0.45in 0.625in 0.45in 0.625in, offset=0.25in 0in, width=6in, clip=true, pagecommand={}]{my_PDF}
\end{document}
```

But now I'm stuck again because it doesn't seem the `\adjustbox` way can select different pages in the multipage PDF (i.e. this second code example repeatedly inserts the same properly-trimmed first page).

Is there a way to make this work? Maybe I'm missing a way to select the pages? Or somehow use the original way to insert the pages, in combination with some sort of `pagecommand={\adjustbox{...}}` key to the `\includepdf` macro? (I tried this too, but I am a relative novice and couldn't get it going) Perhaps there's a totally different method that I'm missing. Basically, I just want to be able to insert a cropped/trimmed multipage PDF document inside an XeTeX document.

Comment: Is it appropriate for you to consider `lualatex`? As far as I recall, clipping should work there (just as for `pdflatex`) because it’s based on PDFTeX whereas `xelatex` creates the PDF from an intermediate “enhanced DVI” format.

Comment: Is it an option for you to generate the cropped pdf first using `pdflatex` and `pdfpages` and subsequently include the cropped pages in the `XeLaTeX` document?

Comment: @MartinHeller Thanks! This is close to the route I took. I ended up using [`pdfcrop2`](http://code.google.com/p/pdfcrop2/source/browse/trunk/pdfcrop.pl), since I didn't have that many pdfs to insert. I'm still curious about if/when there will be a way to solve this without the extra outside step.

Comment: @ilpssun Thanks! This sounds great. I didn't know much about `lualatex` before, but from reading a bit it's sounding like it might eventually surpass `xelatex` for typical users like me. I will definitely give it a shot and see if it goes smoothly or if I bump into any other issues...

Comment: @MartinHeller Would you like to make your comment into an answer? You may also point out that clipping support in XeTeX is work in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Summary of comments as a community wiki answer.]

One option would be to generate a cropped PDF using pdfLaTeX and the `pdfpages` package, and then to use this PDF in a XeLaTeX run. You might also consider LuaLaTeX in place of XeLaTeX, depending on your exact requirements. Clipping for XeLaTeX is now sorted out for `adjustbox`, so you may wish to revisit this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution from

Cropping/Trimming an image with includegraphics by specifying percentages

Trying the following TeX code:

```
\adjustbox{trim=5cm 5cm 5cm 5cm, clip}{\includegraphics[page=2]{source.pdf}}
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a link there...